# How do I make a C program executable on the command line in Minix 3?

Tags: shell, system-calls, minix

I need to make a program, ioloop.c, which takes two command line parameters that determine the number of iterations of two nested for loops.  The inner loop performs a more time-consuming function, such as a trig function.  The outer loop first takes a character from stdin, then outputs some number of characters after the inner loop.

My issue has been finding adequate resources on the internet about Minix 3.  I haven't found any good tutorials yet that explain the process of implementing a command line method.  My first assumption would be that it has something to do with the exec system call.

Any help or explanation on which Minix 3 files are used to implement command line functions would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arguments in main function of program

```
(...)
int main(int artc, char argv[3]){
 int n1 = atoi(argv[1]);
 int n2 = atoi(argv[2]);
(...)
```

Where n1 and n2 are command line parameters. Then if You call

./a.out 100 2000

n1 will be set to 100 and n2 will be 2000

Comment: I tried it, and on the line "int main(int artc, char[] argv)"  I got an error: "expected ';' , ',' or ')' before 'argv'  when I tried to compile.

Comment: That didn't work either, lol, but I figured it out.  The correct syntax was:  int main(int artc, char **argv)